# What's a Laravel/Passport client user_id for?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm a bit confused about the role of `user_id` when creating a new "client" for Laravel/Passport.

I'm using the Authorization Code workflow, where a 3rd party app will access data from my app after the user authorizes it.

From what I understand, this 3rd party app is the "client" and has no reason to be associated with a specific user, as several different users are likely to use it. Am I missing something?

Comment: The client is owned by the user who authorized it, so they can do things like **de**authorizing it.

Comment: OK, so that's for "client management" purpose in the case where users can actually authorize/deauthorize clients.. If I were to manage clients directly in the database (that doesn't sound very clean but well..), then the user_id is rather irrelevant right?

Comment: Sure, if you want to use it that way. You might leave the column and make it nullable, so you can support both use cases.

Answer (score 0):

you are right in the case of authorization flow you won't be using it and probably should be on null, because the authorization flow represents a user giving permission to a client to use its data, now remember there is password grants flow, this flow may be used with only one client (the one you have for default on passport:install command) or you can define a more complex structure where the user is represented by a client and so you will need as many clients as users this is rare as it would mean that each user represents an app but depending on the kind of app or service it may be needed this way.

Also there is the client management scenario. As was mentioned before there are use cases where a user could be an "administrator" to that client and so update values or revoke access, etc.

https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/600.